# Python - ImportError: cannot import name

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-import, cwd

I wrote a simple script that can send notifications via Pushbullet using the pushbullet module, which I installed using pip. I'm using Python 2.7.14.

Now, the script works but I want to trigger it from a bash script and here starts the pain. When I use the bash script the IMPORT command fails when loading the PUSHBULLET module.
I found out that also running the .py script using the syntax:

```
python  pushbullet_test.py
```

fails.
Can someone help me see what I'm doing wrong?

here's the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

STRING="Launching script..."
PYTHON="/usr/bin/python"
SCRIPT_ROOT="/home/ale/Documenti/"
SCRIPT="pushbullet_test.py"
echo "Using $PYTHON"

pushd . 
cd $SCRIPT_ROOT

echo $STRING
$PYTHON "$SCRIPT"

popd
```

This is the python code:

```
import requests
from pushbullet import Pushbullet #THIS IS WHERE IT BREAKS
import sys
batt = "30%"
pb = Pushbullet(api_key="o.blaeudeusadushdufhsfs")
push = pb.push_note("ALERT", "Battery charge lower than {}".format(batt))
```

I found that the script only works when copied into the python terminal, AND when the working directory is my home. Tried to fix it using pushd but it didn't work.

Thank you for any support!

Ale

Comment: How did you install pushbullet?

Comment: And how do you run the python terminal? It's possible that you're using a different python binary to `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, I did with pip install pushbullet.py, following this guide
https://github.com/randomchars/pushbullet.py

Comment: @RobertSeaman, I also tought about that but they seems to match to me, I run python just typing python in bash :-/

Comment: You can't install a single file; so simply copy `pushbullet.py` to wherever your actual script is and it will work.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid thank you for your tip! I figured out that the .py script only runs if it is located in my home directory, no matter where what my cwd is. Is this what you meant?